# Maximum number of swapfiles - kernel documentation bug?

Tags: rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, swap

I'm writing an article about swapfiles. I decided to check how many swapfiles can I create and use. According to `man 2 swapon`, I know that it should be 29 - https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/swapon.2.html. I checked my kernel configuration options with `grep CONFIG_MIGRATION /boot/config-$(uname -r)` and `grep CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE  /boot/config-$(uname -r)`. But when I wrote a simple script to check:

```
for i in {1..33}; do 
    SWAP_FILE="/swapfile-$i"
    sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=$SWAP_FILE bs=1M count=10
    sudo chmod 600 $SWAP_FILE
    sudo mkswap $SWAP_FILE
    sudo swapon $SWAP_FILE
done
```

I was able to activate only 27 of them.

```
[root@localhost ~]# swapon
NAME         TYPE SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile-1  file  10M   0B   -2
(...)
/swapfile-27 file  10M   0B  -28
```

It means that there is probably something missing in the documentation.

I'm using EuroLinux 8 (just another RHEL 8 clone). But I tried it also on Fedora with identical results. I tried to get why this happened by looking into the swap.h kernel file (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/swap.h) but it made me even more confused as there is:

```
#ifdef CONFIG_DEVICE_PRIVATE
#define SWP_DEVICE_NUM 4
#define SWP_DEVICE_WRITE (MAX_SWAPFILES+SWP_HWPOISON_NUM+SWP_MIGRATION_NUM)
#define SWP_DEVICE_READ (MAX_SWAPFILES+SWP_HWPOISON_NUM+SWP_MIGRATION_NUM+1)
#define SWP_DEVICE_EXCLUSIVE_WRITE (MAX_SWAPFILES+SWP_HWPOISON_NUM+SWP_MIGRATION_NUM+2)
#define SWP_DEVICE_EXCLUSIVE_READ (MAX_SWAPFILES+SWP_HWPOISON_NUM+SWP_MIGRATION_NUM+3)
#else
#define SWP_DEVICE_NUM 0
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MIGRATION
#define SWP_MIGRATION_NUM 2
#define SWP_MIGRATION_READ  (MAX_SWAPFILES + SWP_HWPOISON_NUM)
#define SWP_MIGRATION_WRITE (MAX_SWAPFILES + SWP_HWPOISON_NUM + 1)
#else
#define SWP_MIGRATION_NUM 0
#endif
#ifdef CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE
#define SWP_HWPOISON_NUM 1
#define SWP_HWPOISON        MAX_SWAPFILES
#else
#define SWP_HWPOISON_NUM 0
#endif

#define MAX_SWAPFILES \
    ((1 << MAX_SWAPFILES_SHIFT) - SWP_DEVICE_NUM - \
    SWP_MIGRATION_NUM - SWP_HWPOISON_NUM)
```

- (1<< SWAPFILES_SHIFT) = 32 (SWAPFILES_SHIFT=5)
- SWP_DEVICE_NUM is 4 or 0
- SWP_MIGRATION is 2 or 0
- SWP_HWPOISON_NUM is 1 or 0

32 - X = 27 adds only when SWP_DEVICE_NUM and SWP_HWPOISON_NUM is used. At the very same time, the `man 2 swapon` says that:

```
Since kernel 2.6.18, the  limit  is  decreased  by  2
       (thus:  30)  if  the  kernel is built with the CONFIG_MIGRATION
```

And configs are set to yes.

```
[root@fedora ~]# grep CONFIG_MIGRATION /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_MIGRATION=y
[root@fedora ~]# grep CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE  /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_MEMORY_FAILURE=y
```

Any help in understanding why only 27 swaps are available is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely nothing wrong with the docs.

Your misunderstanding simply comes from the fact you are basing your calculus on definitions found in `swap.h` taken from Linus' git, that is the `swap.h` related to the **master branch**, in other words, nowadays ahead of **5.17-rc-1**

While making your experiments under RHEL 8 which, AFAIK, is based on Linux-**4.18**

In [swap.h of 4.18.20](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.20/source/include/linux/swap.h) if we can still read the same formula :

```
#define MAX_SWAPFILES \
    ((1 << MAX_SWAPFILES_SHIFT) - SWP_DEVICE_NUM - \
    SWP_MIGRATION_NUM - SWP_HWPOISON_NUM)
```

`SWP_MIGRATION_NUM` is however taking a different value :

```
#define SWP_MIGRATION_NUM 2
```

**2 instead of 4.**

Applying this value to the formula taking in account your config settings gives:

MAX_SWAPFILES = 32 - 2 - 2 - 1 = **27**

Justifying both the results of your experiments and the documentation.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Based on yours, I will write my own answer later because it was missing from the documentation. I submitted a patch on the kernel manpages list (https://lore.kernel.org/linux-man/d3bc64b3-a1ec-7165-1eed-506d348762c3@euro-linux.com/T/#u) - once merged, I create a new answer - but still, keep yours as the accepted one. Many thanks.

Comment: Thx @AlexBaranowski. Happy to have been of some help. Wishing success for your publication. BTW no worry!, I'm just too old for running after Kudos and badges ;-)